# Single executable with Python and React.js

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, executable

I have two applications

- react.js + node.js app.
- stand alone python app

  I need to merge these two apps and distribute this single app in single executable/binary.
  I understand i need to get rid of node.js and use python as my backend and 
  change calls going from react-node to react-python. And for the latter i need to 
  bring may be Flask.

  For packaging i can use PyInstaller or cx_freeze.

  Any pointers what is the best way to make this merge and create single executable/binary so that final workflow should be like below :

  1) User gets the single executable/binary

  2) Runs/Executes the executable/binary

  3) This fires up the application which can be accessed on browser

  4) User will be able to send request from UI (React) to Backend (Python)

  So basically the single executable/binary has python env, python backend and react(UI) code.

Comment: Why don't you just create an installation package and install all dependencies your app may need instead of trying to shoehorn everything into a single executable?

Comment: @zwer - Thanks for response.Because that will be published so that anyone can download and use it as a product. Or may be I am missing your point. Can you give some example or some reference that i can check/explore?

Comment: I'd package everything with [`pynsist`](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as it leverages [`NSIS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) so you can, technically, bundle everything you want, including even Node.js - although I wouldn't recommend maintaining two different backends for the same thing.

Comment: yes like i mentioned in description i know i need to get rid of node.js and instead have backend built in python and call python from react.So there will be only one backend.

Comment: I think that what @zwer means is that you let it be multiple files, but make an installer, this way you only have 1 executable (The installer) but if they install it it will put all the included files on their computer. (I know this is an old post, oct 2018, but there is a bounty, so I am guessing people still want a answer.)

Comment: How about bundling everything into a Docker container and creating a simple executable that starts the container and launches the web browser to point to the relevant address to the containerized app? Of course this solution may or may not be the best for you depending on a number of factors - eg. if you're looking to build a browser based app wrapped inside a native app, and wether u want Docker as a dependency.

Comment: Did you mean WinZip SFX mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this design structure to solve this problem, it's like all langs, you need to package the front end inside the public folder of your back-end project:

```
.
└── project_template/
    ├── server/
    └── static/
        ├── css/
        ├── images/
        └── js/
```

This project template can be an npm repository that you can customize the script to launch your project.

Example with react and node(you can see the peoject on [GitHub](https://github.com/brunoxd13/poker-hand-analyzer/)):

```
{
  "name": "poker-hand-analyzer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install-frontend-dependencies": "cd ./frontend && yarn install",
    "install-backend-dependencies": "cd ./backend && yarn install",
    "install-dependencies": "yarn install-frontend-dependencies && yarn install-backend-dependencies && yarn install",
    "frontend": "cd ./frontend && yarn start",
    "backend": "cd ./backend && yarn start",
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn frontend\" \"yarn backend\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/brunoxd13/poker-hand-analyzer.git"
  },
  "author": "Bruno Russi Lautenschlager",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/brunoxd13/poker-hand-analyzer/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/brunoxd13/poker-hand-analyzer#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```